# Кодировка в grep

Tags: grep, bash

Нужно найти все файлы, в которые входит определённая строка. Обычно делаю так:

```
grep -rl 'Текст' /path/to/dir
```

однако теперь потребовалось произвести поиск в файлах в кодировке cp1251. Старый вариант уже не отрабатывает. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Для этого я использую `LANG=ru_RU.CP1251 grep -rl 'Текст' /path/to/dir`, настройки терминала должны быть CP1251. Например, в Gnome Terminal или Putty это можно сделать в пару кликов.

Comment: @chernomyrdin да, в терминале тоже надо язык менять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нашлось:

```
find path/to/dir/ -exec grep -il "`echo 'Текст'|iconv -f utf8 -t cp1251`" '{}' \; > result.txt
```

Comment: В комментарии от @chernomyrdin решение лучше (намного эффективнее). При перенаправлении вывода в файл о настройках терминала естественно можно не беспокоиться.

Comment: Вообще-то изменять настройки терминала для решения одной задачи, на мой взгляд, не очень хорошее решение. А что, если придется запускать этот скрипт без иксов?